# drop method in arrayList

Tags: java

I would appreciate if somebody would help me with this task. I have Class NewCar and it works fine but I need to have second class only with one attribute(arrayList) and these four methods w/o constructor.

NewCarList will have the following four methods:
    The add() method will accept a NewCar object and add it to the ArrayList.
    The display() method will display, using toString(), the information about each object in the ArrayList .
The select(double maxPrice) method will do the same thing as display(), except that it will display only the cars with a final price less than or equal to the parameter maxPrice.
The drop(int index) method will delete the NewCar stored in the ArrayList slot with the given index.

```
import java.util.*;

public class NewCarList
{
   ArrayList<NewCar> carList = new ArrayList<>();

   public void add(NewCar)
   {
      carList = NewCar car;
   }

   public void display()
   {

   }

   public void select(double maxPrice)
   {

   }

   public void drop(int index)
   {

   }


}
```

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: This is not a "please do my work for me" site. Please go to the how-to-ask sections of the [help] to see how this site works and to see what questions are required to show.

Comment: I'm not asking you to do work for me , I'm just asking if anybody is available to give me some hints about these methods. If you ara not interested in helping begginers then just ignore questions.

Comment: And btw what is purpose of learning programming if I want others to do work for me?

Comment: @ZvonePandza "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it" according to the site rules.  Showing the code you have so far is good, but perhaps people are expecting you to say what you've tried in your `drop` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for the `ArrayList` class, you'll find several useful methods you can use.

Consider your `drop` method -

> The drop(int index) method will delete the NewCar stored in the ArrayList slot with the given index.

You can use the [`E remove(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) method for this -

> public E remove(int index)
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

Your method would look somewhat like -

```
  public void drop(int index) {
     NewCar removedCar = carList.remove(index);
     if (removedCar != null) {
       System.out.println("Removed car at index: " + index)
     }
     else {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong"); 
     }
   }
```

Similarly, you can use the [public boolean add(E e)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) method to add a `NewCar` object in your arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Your question itself has answers, you need to find appropriate method in `ArrayList` documentation to do what you need.

Asking solution here might give you solution but you wouldn't learn how to read documentation and efficiently use editor features (debugging, etc.) for your future assignments and work.

Here are pointers ...

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

- add()     : Find a method in `ArrayList<T>` which will accept object of type `T` and adds it to itself.
- display() : Implement `toString()` method in your object type `T` class and iterate over all the objects in the `ArrayList` and print them to the console. One more option is to print the whole `ArrayList` in one single `System.out.println` rather than iterating and printing.
- select(double maxPrice) : Iterate over the object type `T` and compare the price of each object with given `maxPrice` to print the desired output.
- drop(int index) : Find method in `ArrayList<T>` which will delete the objects by index.

Here object type `T` is `NewCar`

Add debug points and `System.out.println` in your code so that you can debug yourself and learn how the code is working.